# Use of HibernateTemplate causes 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session'

Tags: hibernate, spring, templates, proxy, initialization

I wish to use a HibernateTemplate instead of a org.hibernate.Session object directly. Unhappily,  the use of a HibernateTemplate causes me the following exception :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:132)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:174)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
at com.els.fu.domain.entities.Contact_$$_javassist_67.getEmail(Contact_$$_javassist_67.java)
at com.els.fu.service.impl.FusionIIEnMasseService.test(FusionIIEnMasseService.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here is a sample code :

```
try {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    MyEntity myEntity = (MyEntity ) session.load(MyEntity.class, 15373482L);
    System.out.println("Test with session : " + myEntity.getEmail());
    myEntity = (MyEntity ) hibernateTemplate.load(MyEntity.class, 15373482L);
    System.out.println("Test with HibernateTemplate: " + myEntity.getEmail());
} finally {
    if (!sessionFactory.isClosed())
        sessionFactory.close();
}
```

The line

```
System.out.println("Test with session : " + myEntity.getEmail())
```

gives me the expected result, but the line

```
System.out.println("Test with HibernateTemplate: " + myEntity.getEmail())
```

causes the error mentionned above. Please do you have any idea of the problem?

You can find further elements about the configuration here :

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.els" />
<!-- Enable @Transactional annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<!-- hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${hibernate.connection.url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${hibernate.connection.username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${hibernate.connection.password}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${hibernate.max_fetch_depth}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">${hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</prop>
            <prop key="connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.characterEncoding">utf-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_entity_mode">pojo</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HibernateTemplate` has its own session, injected by Spring. So you have two session your project: the one in the source code you present, and one in the hibernate template.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but only the sessionFactory is injected by Spring, and I would rather use the HibernateTemplate constructor (There is no HibernateTemplate defined in my applicationContext.xml file)

Comment: @1tox the session factory creates the sessions. Thus Hibernate Template gets its session by this object. So i repeat again: you have TWO sessions, where you must have only one.

Comment: @kartoch When i'm only using the HibernateTemplate (That's to say skipping the sessionFactory.openSession()), I only get one session, right? But in that case, I always get the same error.

Comment: Actually, my problem is how to bound my HibernateTemplate to the current thread in a standalone way. The following code seems to work: `hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory, true);`
   `session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, null, null);`
   **`TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));`**
   **`Contact myEntity = (Contact) hibernateTemplate.load(Contact.class, 15373482L);`**
   `System.out.println(myEntity.getEmail());`

Answer (score 2):

While you post the full stacktrace, here are some tips, to avoid `LazyInitializationException` you can either

- use the JPA annotation `@Fetch(value = FetchType.EAGER)`, if you are using JPA or
- (which is more clean:) use Spring's `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` (for Hibernate `OpenSessionInViewFilter`), a servlet filter which is to be defined in web.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Abalogh, but I'd rather not use the Eager loading mode and I wish to use the piece of code in a standalone way;

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace then :)

Comment: I just did it updating the main post :)

Comment: Do you have @Transactional on your method/class?